# What is the right way to set layout weight programatically?

Tags: android

I see that almost every sample here say that this is the way to set `layout_weight` from the code:

```
linearLayoutView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                     1f));
```

However, this does not work in my case. The only this that works in my case is:

```
linearLayoutView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                    0,
                                                                     1f));
```

which corresponds to XML code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
```

Why is this happening? Is my solution wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said

> which corresponds to XML code

your xml is correct and so is the second code snippet you have because of the `layout_height`. Your `LinearLayout` must have a `vertical orientation` in this situation. For `weight` to work properly, your `layout_width` must be `0dp` and for a `LinearLayout` with a `vertical orientation` your `layout_height` must be `0dp`.

In the first code snippet you have

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

for your `height` which is wrong. It should be 0 as in your second code snippet.